# Add Date Range to SQL Query

Tags: sql

I have the following query which returns the total value of purchase orders against suppliers for a particular company (we have multiple companies in our group).

I want to add a date range using `poheader.orderdate` but as I didn't write this query and it is slightly more complex than I am used to I am not sure where to add this clause.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT  vendor.Vendorid AS 'ID', 
         vendor.name AS 'Name', 
        Total 
FROM    vendor LEFT JOIN 
        (
            select  sum (podetail.orderqty * podetail.unitcost) AS Total, 
                    podetail.VendorNum, 
                    podetail.Company 
            from    podetail 
            where   exists  (
                                select  1 
                                from    poHeader 
                                where   poHeader.OrderNum = podetail.OrderNum 
                                and     poHeader.ApprovalStatus = 'A'
                            ) 
            and     exists  (
                                select  1 
                                from    vendor 
                                WHERE   vendor.company = 'MyCompany' 
                                and     vendor.VendorNum = podetail.VendorNum 
                                and     vendor.Company = podetail.Company
                            ) 
            group by    podetail.VendorNum, 
                        podetail.Company
        ) OD    ON  vendor.Vendornum = OD.Vendornum   
                and vendor.Company = OD.Company 
WHERE   vendor.company = 'MyCompany' 
ORDER BY    vendor.name
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, once it is formatted, it dosnt look all that scary, now does it?

Now you can see where to place the where clause?

Something like

```
SELECT  vendor.Vendorid AS 'ID', 
        vendor.name AS 'Name', 
        Total 
FROM    vendor LEFT JOIN 
        (
            select  sum (podetail.orderqty * podetail.unitcost) AS Total, 
                    podetail.VendorNum, 
                    podetail.Company 
            from    podetail 
            where   exists  (
                                select  1 
                                from    poHeader 
                                where   poHeader.OrderNum = podetail.OrderNum 
                                and     poHeader.ApprovalStatus = 'A'
                                /*-------PLACE THE Date Range Check HERE------*/
                                AND     poheader.orderdate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
                            ) 
            and     exists  (
                                select  1 
                                from    vendor 
                                WHERE   vendor.company = 'MyCompany' 
                                and     vendor.VendorNum = podetail.VendorNum 
                                and     vendor.Company = podetail.Company
                            ) 
            group by    podetail.VendorNum, 
                        podetail.Company
        ) OD    ON  vendor.Vendornum = OD.Vendornum   
                and vendor.Company = OD.Company 
WHERE   vendor.company = 'MyCompany' 
ORDER BY    vendor.name
```

Comment: That certainly makes it easier to get my head around, thanks!

Comment: I've tried adding `AND     poheader.orderdate BETWEEN '2010-11-24' AND `2010-11-25` but the query is returning the same `total`s as it did before adding the date range.  Any ideas why this could be occuring?

Comment: Could it be that this is not working because the `sum (podetail.orderqty * podetail.unitcost)` is outside the first `where exists` statement?

Answer (score 1):

I'm making an assumption as to what you mean by 'add a date range'. I'm assuming you want to filter out the results that fall in a particular range:

```
 SELECT vendor.Vendorid AS 'ID', vendor.name AS 'Name', Total
FROM vendor 
LEFT JOIN (select sum (podetail.orderqty * podetail.unitcost) AS Total, podetail.VendorNum, podetail.Company 
   from podetail 
   where exists
    (select 1 
    from poHeader 
    where poHeader.OrderNum = podetail.OrderNum and poHeader.ApprovalStatus = 'A') 
/*this line*/ and convert(varchar(8),poHeader.orderdate,112) between '20100101' and '20101231' 
   and exists 
    (select 1 from vendor 
    WHERE vendor.company = 'MyCompany' 
    and vendor.VendorNum = podetail.VendorNum 
    and vendor.Company = podetail.Company) 
   group by podetail.VendorNum, podetail.Company) OD 
  ON vendor.Vendornum = OD.Vendornum  
  and vendor.Company = OD.Company
WHERE vendor.company = 'MyCompany'
ORDER BY vendor.name
```

I've reformatted for ease of reading.

I've also converted to a varchar(8), but the parameters that specify a range could be a datetime:

```
and poHeader.orderdate between getdate()-10 and getdate()
```

Comment: The varchar conversion is a great idea, James, thanks.  I've used astander's version above but have added a comment as I'm still getting the same values even with the date filter.

Comment: No worries. Glad to be of help. You got a +15 rep now so you can start voting ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first exists clause should be modified as below:

```
(select 1 from poHeader where poHeader.OrderNum = podetail.OrderNum and poHeader.ApprovalStatus = 'A' and poheader.orderdate BETWEEN 'start_date' AND 'end_date's)
```